# Thunderbird 115.0 Remove duplicate messages

Tags: thunderbird

Anybody knows if does exist a “Remove duplicate messages” add-on compatible with Thunderbird 115.0 (Windows11)?

Comment: Try [Remove Duplicate Messages](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/removedupes/). As it was last updated quiet recently in May 16, 2023, there is a chance that it might work in TB 115.

Comment: Yep, works with TB 115